# Parametric Definite integral

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, definite-integrals

I need to evaluate the definite integral as a function of $t$, say find

$$\phi(t) = \int _0^{\infty} \exp\left(-\sqrt{x^2+t^2}\right)dx$$

and check continuity and differentiablity at $t=0$.

Comment: Since $e^{-(x^{2}+t^{2})}=e^{-x^{2}}\cdot e^{-t^{2}}$, you can factor out the $t$-dependence and calculate the integral

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(note that continuity and differentiability at $t=0$ can be discussed without evaluating the integral)

Assume $t>0$, after the substitution $x= t \sinh \xi$, we obtain the result
$$\phi(t) = t\int_0^\infty\!d\xi\,e^{-t \cosh \xi} \cosh\xi. $$

This is a well-known representation of the [modified Bessel function of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions:_I.CE.B1_.2C_K.CE.B1). We obtain
$$\phi(t) =t K_1(t) .$$

You can obtain the answers to your questions from the expansion (valid for small $t$)
$$ K_1(t) = \frac1t + \frac14 t \left( \log\left(\frac{t^2}4\right) +2 \gamma -1\right) + O(t^3)$$
with $\gamma$ the Euler–Mascheroni constant.

Comment: :Please mark some references for the expansion! The answer is very helpful!

Comment: It is implicitly contained e.g. in Abramovitz-Stegun. Or explicitly [here](http://functions.wolfram.com/Bessel-TypeFunctions/BesselK/06/01/04/01/02/).